# How to join the next date value of the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL with the following fields:

[image]

The `timestamp` field will have all the punches that an employee has in a day.

So having the following data:

[image]

I need to create 2 diferent queries.

> 1. need to select all the IN timestamps with their corresponding next OUT timestamp
> 2. need to select all the OUT timestamps with their corresponding previous IN timestamp

So, in the first query, I should get the following:

[image]

In the second query, I should get the following:

[image]

> Any clue on how to build such queries?

**HERE IS THE Fiddle**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a137d/1

Comment: Can you prepare sample data in SQL Fiddle?

Comment: Sure... let me do that

Comment: This is a common problem. Perhaps you coudl do some research and have a try at a query. Also consider what happens when someone punches in twice then out. How about punches out twice?

Comment: Does each in has an out and vise versa. Also what version of SQL Server are we to use. Because we can use ether ctr or cross apply to accomplish this.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - Actually OP has `IN`-`IN`-`OUT` case and explains how s/he wants it handled.

Comment: Oh yes you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for.  These queries should work on most DBMSs.

First

```
SELECT ea1.employeeid, ea1.timestamp AS instamp, ea2.timestamp AS outstamp
FROM employee_attendance ea1
LEFT JOIN employee_attendance ea2 
ON ea2.employeeid=ea1.employeeid 
AND ea2.accesscode = 'OUT' 
AND ea2.timestamp = (
    SELECT MIN(ea3.timestamp)
    FROM employee_attendance ea3
    WHERE ea3.timestamp > ea1.timestamp
    AND ea3.employeeid = ea1.employeeid
)
WHERE ea1.accessCode = 'IN'
AND ea1.employeeid = 4;
```

Second

```
SELECT ea1.employeeid, ea1.timestamp AS outstamp, ea2.timestamp AS instamp
FROM employee_attendance ea1
LEFT JOIN employee_attendance ea2 
ON ea2.employeeid=ea1.employeeid 
AND ea2.accesscode = 'IN' 
AND ea2.timestamp = (
    SELECT MIN(ea3.timestamp)
        FROM employee_attendance ea3
        WHERE ea3.timestamp < ea1.timestamp
        AND ea3.employeeid = ea1.employeeid
        AND ea3.timestamp > ISNULL((
            SELECT MAX(ea4.timestamp)
            FROM employee_attendance ea4
            WHERE ea4.accesscode = 'OUT'
            AND ea4.timestamp < ea1.timestamp
            AND ea4.employeeid = ea1.employeeid
        ), '2000-1-1')
)
WHERE ea1.accessCode = 'OUT'
AND ea1.employeeid = 4;
```

Comment: Hi Jesse, the last query, the last row is returning the last IN instead of the previous IN. The correct timestamp is: 14:28:20

Comment: Ah, Didn't notice that part.  So you want to disregard any double "IN"s?

Comment: You do have that `timestamp` field indexed right?  Also an index on  `accesscode` might help if you see bad performance.

Comment: Oh and `employeeid`, all of the fields in this table could probably benefit from being indexed if you are going to query it in this manner.

Comment: Curious.  Can the double out scenario occur? If so then the first query may need to be modified in a similar way to how I modified the second.

Comment: @VAAA So... did this work for you?  I kind of need the reputation points so that I can start interacting with the community better, so if this worked for you I would appreciate the points.  If not, I'd like to know what was wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like nice example for usage of LEAD, LAG ANALYTIC functions in SQL 2012.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT EMPLOYEEID, TIMESTAMP,
  LEAD(timestamp) OVER (ORDER BY TIMESTAMP
  ) OUTTIMESTAMP, ACCESSCODE

  FROM [dbo].[employee_attendance]
  WHERE EMPLOYEEID =4 

) T 
where T.ACCESSCODE ='IN'
```

second query

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT EMPLOYEEID, TIMESTAMP,
  LAG(timestamp) OVER (ORDER BY TIMESTAMP
  ) INTIMESTAMP, ACCESSCODE

  FROM [dbo].[employee_attendance]
  WHERE EMPLOYEEID =4 

) T 
where T.ACCESSCODE ='OUT'
```

Comment: The out query is not giving the right result. If you look to the last result I´m getting the last IN instead of the first IN. The correct timestamp is: 14:28:20

Comment: second query also, you can use LEAD, so that you get previous IN

Comment: actually LAG is correct, only thing there are two INs in the same date, so it was picking up the last IN instead of first IN

Comment: Can you do the changes so the queries?

Comment: just curious, how is employee in twice once at 2:28 and again at 2:30 with out a out

Comment: Error of anti-passback but happens.